# How to define APIView's url?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to make an APIView with the Django Rest Framework. When I associate the view with the url, I got this error :

`AssertionError: basename argument not specified, and could not automatically determine the name from the viewset, as it does not have a .queryset attribute.`

Here is mys APIView :

```
class ExampleView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        content = {
            'user': unicode(request.user),  # `django.contrib.auth.User` instance.
            'auth': unicode(request.auth),  # None
        }
        return Response(content)
```

And the router :

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('api/example', views.ExampleView.as_view())
```

So, what's wrong ? Thank you !

Comment: You wouldn't use a router for this. They're for viewsets.

Comment: if still, you want to use `routers` then you also need to define `basename` argument like this >> 
```router.register('api/example', views.ExampleView.as_view(), basename='example')```
Check out more at https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You just need to add the path to your `urlpatterns`. Routers are used with viewsets.

```
from django.urls import path

app_name = 'example'

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/example', views.ExampleView.as_view(), name='example')
]
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification over Routers being used with viewsets. The DRF tutorial seems to pass over a number of things for using less abstracted classes and this is one of them.